# AES init vector

Tags: vector, key, aes, init

Do I have provide AES key + IV for someone to be able to decrypt encrypted data?
Does that increase key length from 128 bit to 256 bits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both the key and the IV are needed to decrypt something. Generally, the key should be exchanged using a secure channel or key exchange mechanism. The IV can be transmitted along with the encrypted data in plain text. An IV should ideally be used only once. The main motivation behind using a changing IV is that encrypting the same thing twice should not result in the same ciphertext both times, because this can allow an attacker to draw conclusions about the data encrypted.

Comment: BTW one extra question - is it ok if I attach init vector (random for each file) to begining of it (after encrypting file itself with AES)  and share AES key encrypted with RSA?

Comment: Yes, that seems fine. A weak point with this would be the exchange of the RSA public key, which could be susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks. A construction like this would be very similar to TLS without certificate validation. May I ask what you plan to use the encryption for? It is often better to use an established standard like TLS for things like this rather than implement it yourself.

Comment: Ohh nothing special - just handling of biometry identifiers for goverment institution! ;)

Comment: I meant the question in a more technical way. For example, are you trying to secure a custom TCP/IP protocol or a web service? In that case, I would definitely recommend wrapping the communication using TLS / HTTPS instead of a custom-made encryption. However, that recommendation may be useless if you are for example trying to secure files stored on a hard disk or something similar.

Comment: Yep. Exactly. I have to secure offline biometry identifiers which latter on will be brought to server (usb/network/whatever). I just wanted to know - is that ok to store IV unencrypted or is it that I can gain further more security by encrypting IV with RSA as well.

Comment: dosendoc - i tried with using not-initialized init vector for decrypting and only very first part of file came out wrong, but rest of file decrypted well. Is this expected behavior of AES?

Comment: This sounds like the IV was only applied while encrypting the first block and that a regular ECB mode of operation was used (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) so that the other blocks weren't affected. You should make sure that you use a chaining mode of operation like CBC for adequate security.